# I have a question concerning a inserted pdf file in a LaTex document

Tags: pdfpages

I have following code in Latex:

```
\begin{figure}

\includepdf[pages=-,scale=.8,pagecommand={},linktodoc=true]{Scanned Documents.pdf}

\end{figure}

\end{itemize}
```

There is text before the inserted file. However, if I want to continue with a text between `\end{figure}` and `\end{itemize}`, the text shows up on the inserted pdf document which does not fill a whole page (it is basically a picture). I don't know what I have to add so I can write plain text that continues after the pdf file ?

Thanks in advance and as it is my first time asking on such a page pleas tell me, if there are missing information.

Comment: don't use \includepdf, but \includegraphics.

Comment: I tried \includegraphics. It then puts the pdf file on a new page bellow. I need it to be like following: "text" "pdf-file" "text". However, on the same page.

Comment: Additional for Ulrikes comment: `\includepdf` will insert entire pages and thus makes no sense in a figure as its contents by definition need to fit within the size of the text block.

Comment: No you don't! Add a caption to your figure and refer to the figure by name. Don't assume that the figure is **here** or **below**. Let the figure float and refer to it by number. Then you don't waste paper when the figure does not fit right here and has to be moved to a different page. Additionally you might want to use `\begin{figure}[htbp]` as the `h` is not included by default. Note that `h` means _here if possible_

Comment: then don't use a figure environment.

Comment: I see. Thank you!